# Composer: Packages not found on server, but on local machine

Tags: php, composer-php

I have two identical `composer.json` on my local windows machine and my linux dev server:

```
"name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
"description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
"keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
"homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
"type": "project",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
    "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
    "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
    "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
    "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.6",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-jui": "^2.0",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2": "@dev",
    "2amigos/yii2-file-upload-widget": "~1.0",
    "cozumel/yii2-image-cropper": "*",
    "yii2mod/yii2-ion-slider": "*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",

    "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
    "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1"
},
"config": {
    "process-timeout": 1800,
    "fxp-asset":{
        "installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    }
}
```

On my local machine, I can update composer without any problems:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 4 updates, 0 removals
  - Updating yiisoft/yii2-debug (2.0.9 => 2.0.10): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating bower-asset/blueimp-file-upload (v9.19.0 => v9.19.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating phpspec/prophecy (v1.7.0 => v1.7.2): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2 dev-master (a129c66 => 2c3f475):  Checking out 2c3f47527c
Writing lock file
```

Generating autoload files

Yet on my server, I get the error that the packages could not be found:

```
$ composer update
You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.x-dev requires bower-asset/punycode 1.3.* -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.9 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.8 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.7 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.6 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.12 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.11.2 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.11.1 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.11 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.10 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2 ~2.0.6 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.10, 2.0.11, 2.0.11.1, 2.0.11.2, 2.0.12, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.0.9, 2.0.x-dev].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

After quite some hours of searching around, I still don't have any clue where to even begin with.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to the end of your composer.json:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
    }
]
```

Since the server can't find any packages, there seem to be something wrong with the repository definition. Not sure, but in your local composer environment the repo above may have been defined outside of your composer.json (as a default perhaps).